# Deploying rails app via capistrano on nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, spree, unicorn

While trying to deploy my spree rails app on a Amazon EC2 server, I am getting this error: `config/unicorn.rb:3:in 'reload': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) (ArgumentError)` when I run `cap unicorn:start`

**EDITED:**

Here is my full `config/unicorn.rb`: http://pastie.org/8738481

and `config/deploy.rb`: http://pastie.org/8735891

full error: http://pastie.org/8738485

AND,
when I run `bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E development` I get

`master failed to start, check stderr log for details`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing line 3 in `config/unicorn.rb` with `set[:application] = "manndi"`.

Comment: I have updated my question according to your answer. still my problem isn't solved :(

Comment: Line 3 is empty in your updated question, is the error log updated as well?

Comment: yes it is. that is what stuns me the most. could you run this on your machine somehow and see if this error is reproducible?

Comment: You say you get the error when you run bundle, but the error log is for a cap command. You use git for deployment, so did you commit and pushed the change to your repo? If not, please do then run the cap command again.

Comment: I just updated my repo. Same error. But there is a different error when I run `bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E development` locally, as I have mentioned in my question

Comment: `master failed to start, check stderr log for details`

Comment: How about deploying your code again, just to make sure the code is updated upstream, as `cap unicorn:start` doesn't update the code.